# How to print the correct message based on condition.

Tags: python, http

I have this python script which displays a message based on a website's status. According to the script below, the message is suppose to be "Service is Operating Normally". Instead the other message: "Something is Going On" is shown.

```
import urllib.request
Status = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.stackoverflow.com").getcode()
if (Status == "200"):
    print ("Service is Operating Normally")
else:
    print ("Something is Going On")
```

What would be the proper solution for this?

Thanks,

Comment: The status returned is <'int'> type so Status == 200.

Comment: Depending on your task, merely checking the HTTP server's result code may not be good enough to detect an actual malfunction. The server could be serving up the wrong page, for example. But as part of a bigger decision tree, this is of course a good start.

Comment: Be carefull: 200 = OK but the service may be available at another URI (301). IMO you should test if (status begin by 3 or 2) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Status` is a number 200, not a string `"200"`. You should compare apples to apples:

```
if Status==200:
    ....
```